# app.start() returns can't create process access is denied error

Tags: python, python-3.x, access-denied, pywinauto, pyautogui

I'm working on gui-automation using pyautogui and pywinauto(Python). I tried starting a .exe file via a remote desktop connection (windows server 2008) but app.start returns "Can't create process, access is denied" error. I tried granting full control access too, but that doesn't help.Is there any solution for this?

I pass my user credentials while connecting, and the connection gets established too.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RDP connection doesn't pass any GUI text information. You have to run the automation script on the remote machine (script should be stored on the same remote machine also). It's also possible to use PsExec or Ansible from local machine to run the automation remotely. See details here (second rated answer):

https://serverfault.com/questions/690852/use-powershell-to-start-a-gui-program-on-a-remote-machine

Comment: Thank you,I have now solved the issue. The problem now is the .exe application which is in the remote machine is running locally. I want it to run in the remote machine itself. Any comments on that??

Comment: You need local runner (see the link in the answer) -> remote automation script -> an .exe. The only first component could be on local machine. Python+pywinauto should run on remote one as well.